# Visualize uber h3 hexagon in Power BI

Tags: python, geojson, visualisation, h3, business-intelligence

I have two columns. One is h3 index and other is quantifying column. I have converted each hexagon into WKT. I am not sure how I can display hexagons over a map in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of representation of h3 index, However you can visualize them on powerBI

1. using Iconmaps plugin by creating the Shape file of h3index polygons.
2. Using Shapemap plugin of powerBI (without basemap) by generating the TOPOJson file of h3index with "h3index" as identity and then match it with your dataset.

please ask if more clarity is needed.